# Select with join testing two different datasets on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I have a database on which users has and belong to many "activities", and those activities are grouped by an activity_type:

Let's say i have a Users table

```
users
-------
id
name
.....
```

And an Activity table and type

```
activities
----------
id
name
activity_type_id
```

.

```
activity_types
--------------
id
name
```

And a join table

```
activities_users
------------------
user_id
activity_id
```

**So the question is:**

*If i have activity_type ids 5 and 7, and need to make a query that brings the users who have been in activities of type 5 AND 7.*

*How can then this query be achieved?*

Tried this:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.phone FROM users
JOIN activities_users ON (
  users.id = activities_users.user_id  AND
  (
    activities_users.activity_id IN (SELECT activities.id FROM activities where activities.activity_type_id IN (5))
    AND
    activities_users.activity_id IN (SELECT activities.id FROM activities where activities.activity_type_id IN (7))
  )
);
```

But realize i will have an empty set because activity_id on the 5th line will never be in one dataset and the other simultaneously.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Well i think i had to make two different JOIN aliasing the join table with a different name each time:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.phone FROM users
JOIN activities_users AS au1 ON (
  users.id = au1.user_id  
  AND au1.activity_id IN (SELECT activities.id FROM activities where activities.activity_type_id IN (5))
)
JOIN activities_users AS au2 ON (
  users.id = au2.user_id  
  AND au2.activity_id IN (SELECT activities.id FROM activities where activities.activity_type_id IN (7))
)
group by users.id;
```

More optimal answers are still appreciated anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE EXISTS
           (SELECT NULL
              FROM activity_types
                   INNER JOIN activities ON activities.activity_type_id = activity_types.id
                   INNER JOIN activities_users ON activities_users.activity_id = activities.id
             WHERE activity_types.id IN (5, 7)
               AND activity_users.user_id = users.id)
```